# How to delete message logs in twilio trial account?

Tags: twilio-php

I am using twilio trial account for sending message and it generate SMS logs.
 I want to remove all SMS logs from my trial account of twilio.
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP helper library to redact the body of a message, or delete the entire message resource:

```
$client = new Services_Twilio('AC123', '123');
$message = $client->account->messages->get("MM123");
$message->redact(); // Erases 'Body' field contents
$message->delete(); // Deletes entire message record
```

More info on deleting message can be [found in our docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#instance-delete).

Hope that helps.

Comment: What is argument of get() method?

Comment: The Sid of the message you want to delete.